# Javassist - get array length

Tags: java, arrays, javassist

Can somebody please help me in method for finding array length in javassist? I have a class with one static array inside:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static String arr[] = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
}
```

Now, in the other class, I'm loading SomeClass and trying to get length of the arr Array.

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = classPool.get("SomeClass");

ctClass.getField("arr") //<---------- HOW TO GET LENGTH HERE?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code represents the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static String[] arr;

  static {
    arr = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
  }
}
```

In order to read the array's length, you need to parse the class initializer and interpret its byte code. Javassist has no built-in functionality for extracting this information.